# Issue using two loops in python

Tags: python

Hey currently I'm dealing with for loops issue with my code and wondering if any of you can give me any insight

I'm trying to print text from a 2 files, and kind of merged them when printing.
Two of the files contain the same amount of lines.

Here's my code so far:

```
links = open("link.txt", "r")
names = open("name.txt", "r")

for link in links:
    for name in names:
        print(link.strip(), "=", name.strip())
```

The loop for the name actually working, but the link doesnt, it stuck on the first line

Comment: When you say "kind of merged", exactly what do you mean?  If the files have the same number of lines, it's each with `zip`.  If not, then you have to tell us what you need.

Comment: Your code currently says "for each link, loop over all names", not "look at each link and name element together"

Comment: @TimRoberts hey yeah I actually tried to google search if both file have the same number of lines, but nothing really came up, so I decided to sign myself up here, and ask my very first question. Sorry if my way of asking question is no good

Comment: @OneCricketeer Huh, that's where my mistake is, not looping both together. I have a lot to learn, sorry again!

Answer (score 3):

If the files have the same number of lines:

```
links = open("link.txt", "r")
names = open("name.txt", "r")

for link,name in zip(links,names):
    print(link.strip(), "=", name.strip())
```